# How to download Unicode CLDR JSON data with cldr-data-downloader behind proxy server?

Tags: node.js, cldr

I would like to use cldr-data-downloader(https://github.com/rxaviers/cldr-data-downloader) behind proxy server.
The document says exec the command below.

```
enter code here$ npm install cldr-data-downloader
Using the CLI:

$ ./node_modules/cldr-data-downloader/bin/download.sh \
    -i http://www.unicode.org/Public/cldr/26/json.zip \
    -o ./cldr

GET `http://www.unicode.org/Public/cldr/26/json.zip`
  [========================================] 100% 0.0s
Received 3425K total.

Unpacking it into ./cldr
```

I can exec this command without error when I try it without proxy, but it cause error when I execute it from behind proxy server.
I suspicious that I need to the proxy address to this application but I don't know how should I do it.

Does someone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve the issue by myself.
Solution is to set HTTP_PROXY value

on windows

```
 set HTTP_PROXY = http://your.proxy.address:port
```

on Linux

```
export HTTP_PROXY = http://your.proxy.address:port
```

CLDR downloader check this value, but npm and bower checks different config files. in short, You have to set proxy value separately for npm, bower and CLDR downloader.(and gradle if you are using it)